# Kotlin serialization of value class that implements a sealed interface

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlin-sealed

I am trying to use Kotlin serialization (Kotlin 1.7.2, kotlinx.serialization 1.4.1) for value classes that implement a sealed interface:

```
@Serializable
sealed interface Power {
    val value: Int
}

@Serializable
@JvmInline
value class PowerWatt(override val value: Int) : Power

@Serializable
@JvmInline
value class PowerHp(override val value: Int) : Power
```

When attempting serialization to Json, like so:

```
    @Test
    fun `Correctly serialize and deserialize a value class that implements a sealed interface`() {
        val power: Power = PowerWatt(123)
        val powerSerialized = Json.encodeToString(power)
        val powerDeserialized = Json.decodeFromString<Power>(powerSerialized)
        assertEquals(power, powerDeserialized)
    }
```

I run into the following error:

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject as the serialized body of Power, but had class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonLiteral

    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonExceptionsKt.JsonDecodingException(JsonExceptions.kt:24)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:94)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:81)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:95)
```

How to make this work? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you'll insert it into an object it will work as expected. the problem is that you serialize a primitive type of Int into a String - and you get actually an Int. i.e. s: String = "123", which is a Json primitive

Comment: Hm, I don't quite understand this. I do not want to wrap the types into objects (that is, I do not want to use data classes instead of value classes. And I do not see where I explicitly ask for Ints to be serialized as strings, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided in a Kotlin Serialization GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/2049#issuecomment-1271536271). For value classes, the wrapped underlying type is serialized directly. Hence, there is not wrapping JSON object where the `type` field for the polymorphic serializer could be inserted.